# AutoLogout after 5 minutes of inactivity Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Before posting, i did look on google but found no answer. I would like to pop an alert after 5 minutes of inactivity and autologout if user is idle. But in Swift, I am unable to find any guide or resource for it. Anyone able to give some guide on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way to do this and that is via the AppDelegate.swift file. It is the only place to add the code for the complete app to respond to x amount of idle time before logout.

Inside your "class AppDelegate" add the following code:

```
func addObjForIdleTime(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                                        self,
                                        selector: #selector(showAlert_idle),
                                        name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showAlert_idle"),
                                        object: nil
                                        )
}

@objc func showAlert_idle(){
    
    setLoginType() //do you logout here

}
```

Add a new function below the "class AppDelegate"

```
class CustomApplication: UIApplication {
private var timerToDetectInactivity: Timer?
private var timeIdleSecond: TimeInterval {
    return 5 * 60  // 5 min.
}

override func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent) {
    //print("sendEvent... ")

    super.sendEvent(event)
    if let touches = event.allTouches {
        for touch in touches where touch.phase == UITouch.Phase.began {
            self.resetTimer()
        }
    }
}

// reset the timer because there was user event
private func resetTimer() {
    //print("resetTimer... ")

    if let timerToDetectInactivity = timerToDetectInactivity {
        timerToDetectInactivity.invalidate()
    }

    timerToDetectInactivity = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeIdleSecond,
                                     target: self,
                                     selector: #selector(CustomApplication.showAlert),
                                     userInfo: nil,
                                     repeats: false
    )
}

@objc private func showAlert() {
    //print("showAlert and logout... ")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("showAlert_idle"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
}
```

}

Modify main.swift and add CustomApplication:

```
UIApplicationMain(
    CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv,
    NSStringFromClass(CustomApplication.self),
    NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
```

Modify the time you want to auto logout by changing return 5 * 60  // 5 min.

Comment: The timer will get suspended when the user locks the screen. instead of a timer don't you think using some date-time will be better?

Comment: Yes, please add your suggestion and repost the code for the thread.

Comment: @SebastienDesemberg where to add this code UIApplicationMain(
    CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv,
    NSStringFromClass(CustomApplication.self),
    NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
) - not able to find main.swift file in my swift  project

Comment: @NikitaPatil You need to create a main.swift file and add the code to the file

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var timer = Timer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 300, target: self, selector: #selector(userIsInactive), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    let timerGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(resetTimer))
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(timerGesture)
 }

@objc func userIsInactive() {
    // Alert user
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "You have been inactive for 5 minutes. We're going to log you off for security reasons.", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
    //Log user off
    }))
    present(alert, animated: true)

    timer.invalidate()
 }

@objc func resetTimer() {
    print("Reset")
    timer.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 300, target: self, selector: #selector(userIsInactive), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: but i would need to add this to every single view? is there any way i can do it once and all view works?

Comment: @L.William - do you want to do this in  when app in background only or else

Comment: when app is being used @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @L.William - see this for help : https://blog.gaelfoppolo.com/detecting-user-inactivity-in-ios-application-684b0eeeef5b